# Update table with greatest value from itself and another table

Tags: sql, mysql

I have two tables A and B with some data and a date (e.g. date of last update). The id is only unique in table A. I want to update table A with the last date (=maximum) for each id.

Table A:

```
id date maximum
---------------
1  5    NULL
2  6    NULL
```

Table B:

```
id date
-------
1  3
1  7
2  20
```

Result A after Update:

```
id date maximum
---------------
1  5    7
2  6    20
```

What I got so far works, but it looks kind of weird:

```
UPDATE a,b 
SET a.maximum = (
  SELECT GREATEST(MAX(b.date),a.date) WHERE a.id=b.id GROUP BY b.id) 
WHERE a.id = b.id
;
```

The double `WHERE a.id=b.id` confuses me especially. Can this be improved somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would update with a join to a derived table. This would likely perform better than your subselect as well as be more intuitive to read (in my opinion, at least).

```
UPDATE a
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
        id,
        MAX(`date`) AS max_date
    FROM b
    GROUP BY id
) AS max_dates
    ON a.id = max_dates.id
SET a.maximum = GREATEST(a.`date`, max_dates.max_date)
```